# Clarification: $\{x^{\alpha}\}$ total in $L^2[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I've come across the following remark without many details:

> For $\alpha \in \{0, 1, \dots\}$, the sequence $\{x^{\alpha}\}$ is total in $L^2[a,b]$.

By total, I mean $X = \{x^{\alpha}\}$, then $\overline{\text{span}}(X) = L^2[a,b]$.

---

I generally recall we can use some theorems/strategies relating to Hilbert spaces here, but am rusty. Does the following make sense more or less:

i) Since $L^2[a,b]$ forms an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, we know there exists some orthonormal (is total) basis $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

ii) Let $f \in L^2[a,b]$. If $\langle f, x^{\alpha} \rangle = 0$ for all $\alpha$, then $f = 0$, and it follows that $x^{\alpha}$ is total in $L^2[a,b]$. We aim to show this.

iii) By Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\langle f, e_n - x^{\alpha} \rangle| \leq ||f||_2||e_n - x^{\alpha}||_2$. Thus, the general Pythagorean Theorem (I forget actual name) implies

$$||f||^2_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f, e_n - x^{\alpha}\rangle|^2 \leq ||f||_2^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||e_n - x^{\alpha}||_2^2.$$

iv) By Weierstrass, we know for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $||e_n - p||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. Therefore,
$$||\epsilon_n - p||_2^2 \leq (b-a)||\epsilon_n - p||_{\infty}  \quad\Rightarrow\quad ||f||_2^2 \leq ||f||_2^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = ||f||_2^2(b-a)\epsilon,$$

and therefore we must have $f = 0$ for equality.

Comment: finite-dimensional?

Comment: sorry, infinite-dim. fixed.

Comment: Minor comment: In your last step you use $||e_n-p||_2^2\leq ||e_n-p||_\infty$. However, it should be: $||e_n-p||_2^2\leq (b-a)||e_n-p||_\infty$

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. Added in.

Comment: I think your proof is over-talked. All you need is the last point, i.e. polynomials are dense in $C[a,b]$ and continuous functions are dense in $L^2[a,b]$.